# Inline citations in Doxygen documentation

Tags: documentation, doxygen, bibtex, bibliography, citations

Is it possible to insert inline (in-text) citations in the documentation with Doxygen? Normally when you use `\cite <bibtex_id>` it inserts the bibliography index of the paper in brackets like `[3]`. However I want to insert the bibliography item itself. It would be great to list bibiliography references in the **See also** section with `\see`.

Is it possible?

Comment: At the moment this is not possible, but a nice and complex enhancement.